# When is implementing IHttpAsyncHandler worth the trouble?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I'm looking at implementing `IHttpAsyncHandler` in an application and am not sure if it's useful in my scenario.  Which metrics specifically indicate when this is worth the extra trouble?

Comment: It might be better to post your planned use case, and ask for critiques on that, rather than asking an enumeration of every appropriate and inappropriate case.

Comment: @David Souther, I'm asking about metrics, not use cases.  My use case is I have an app with some level of concurrent usage.  I'd like to know when that level will benefit from IHttpAsyncHandler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article seems to offer some insight: http://vladsnotes.hrybok.com/PermaLink,guid,7885abfa-f502-429f-8016-309e233e4554.aspx

It seems there are few circumstances where IHttpAsyncHandlers could be "worth the trouble".

Comment: Thanks.  How do you know "if you are running out of request processing threads"?

Comment: I guess you'd have to fire-up performance monitor and keep an eye on any errors appearing (use Event Viewer)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you mean specifically by metrics, but the most important is probably the number of concurrent threads in your app.

If you have a lot of threads, maybe maxing the pool, you probably should first consider raising the thread pool. If that still doesn't satisfy you, then it might be time to use IHttpAsyncHandler.

Comment: It seems that the switch to IHttpAsyncHandler would offer you less control over the creation of new threads: it would theoretically be possible to exceed the max number of threads the OS can support